# TypeScript error: Property 'length' does not exist on type '{ user: any; pwd: any; }'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, build, compiler-errors, yarnpkg

I'm compiling my development environment and ran into the below TypeScript error. This prevented the build from compiling.

Here is the text from my terminal:

```
Property 'length' does not exist on type '{ user: any; pwd: any; }'.  TS2339

    50 |       .post(`${settings.env.production.apiUrl}/api/login`, { user, pwd })
    51 |       .then((response) => {
  > 52 |         if (response.data.length !== 0) {
       |                           ^
    53 |           sessionStorage.setItem("logged-in", "true");
    54 |           sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data[0]));
    55 |           this.setState({ loggedIn: true, user: response.data[0] });


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Here is the full function:

```
login = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const user = event.target.querySelector("input[type='email']").value;
    const pwd = event.target.querySelector("input[type='password']").value;
    // perform login api call...
    axios
      .post(`${settings.env.production.apiUrl}/api/login`, { user, pwd })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.length !== 0) {
          sessionStorage.setItem("logged-in", "true");
          sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data[0]));
          this.setState({ loggedIn: true, user: response.data[0] });
        } else {
          sessionStorage.setItem("logged-in", "false");
          alert("Sorry, bad login attempt.");
        }
      });
  };
```

Any help is greatly appreciated in compiling this build.  Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't look like TypeScript code. You don't have any type annotations telling TypeScript what type `event` is, or what the response from `axios` would be, for instance (perhaps the former is defined where `login` is declared). What have you done to track down the problem? It seems very odd that TypeScript should thinks `response.data` is of type `{user: any, pwd: any}`; that's the format of the post data, not the response.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I apologize if this does not look like TypeScript code.  It is from a `.tsx` file in Reactjs.  I hope that makes my question more clear.  - Thank you.